# Use Azure for desktop application log

Tags: c#, azure

I have an 'offline' WPF application that I want to release to users. 
It was not using any cloud technologies, but I want to start using it - for now, for user registration, application logs and updates.

Currently, I have the application log designed with StreamWriter to a local file on the user machine.

I would like to stop using a single local log file for each machine and rather have all instances of my WPF app to append the same log file in Azure.

I already have an azure account and a simple database there for registered users and a blob for the updated app download.

But what is the best approach for creating and appending a text file? My main concern is performance and reliability - I don't want this to make ma app slower and less stable.

Thanks
Bartek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it in a local log file as for now, and create a background worker which will for changes in the local log file, and save newly added local log items in Azure Table Storage - which is really fast and in my opinion the best technology for such use case. Such approach should have no impact in the user experience in your application.

Comment: Do you mean to do it on a specific interval (e.g. 5 minutes) or just whenever the file is changed?

Comment: And also - if that's a table storage, then would it not grow extremely large after a couple of months? I suppose I might have up to a hundred users, so I rather wanted to dump logs into files - one per day...

Comment: You can use  FileSystemWatcher to check if file is changed.

Comment: Table Storage does not have problems with huge data -http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/12/working-with-154-million-records-on.html

Answer (score 1):

You could also let the WPF Application asynchronously push the logs to Azure Storage Queue and let a separate process sitting on cloud (worker role/web job) take messages and append them to files in azure blob storage (blobs/containers) accordingly. In this way I think you can neatly layout your containers/blobs and scale the logging job independently and of course you have files now !!

Please do consider the storage and bandwidth limitation of Azure Storage Queues if your following this approach.

Let me know your comments, Thanks.